# Setup Xdebug and PHPStorm with remote server

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug a PHP script using Xdebug and PHPStorm on a remote server, and am quite new to remote debugging.  I do not have full access to the server but have FTP (not SFTP) access to most of the files (I can't get to php.ini for example).

Xdebug is installed on the server correctly according to the wizard on their website and uses default values.

I have all project files downloaded and setup in a project, which is setup for deployment.  This works fine.

To setup debugging I've installed WAMP on my local box (not the remote server, obviously) and set it as my PHP interpreter. It uses the same version of PHP as the remote server.

I set a breakpoint and tried to establish the connection by setting PHPStorm to listen and using the bookmarklet to set the browser to start debugging.  It didn't work so I then tried to setup a new PHP Remote Debug server in run > edit configurations.  The "Validate remote environment" button says "Remote host: localhost".  I'm still not able to get a connection either by setting to listen, or clicking debug with the server I setup, or both.

What do I need to do to get PHPStorm to establish the connection?

Edit:

I am debugging a Magento module.

If any changes need to be made on the remote server I can request them, but my current understanding is that the remote server is setup correctly, and the problem is me and my setup.

from the xdebug.org wizard about the remote server-

> Tailored Installation Instructions
>
> Summary
>
> - Xdebug installed: 2.2.2
> - Server API: FPM/FastCGI
> - Windows: no
> - Zend Server: no
> - PHP Version: 5.3.24
> - Zend API nr: 220090626
> - PHP API nr: 20090626
> - Debug Build: no
> - Thread Safe Build: no
> - Configuration File Path: /etc
> - Configuration File: /etc/php.ini
> - Extensions directory: /usr/lib64/php/modules

edit 2:
I wanted to post some screen caps, but I'm a single rep point shy.

I've tried it with both the IDE Key PHPSTORM and none.  neither worked.

here is the Xdebug section of phpinfo().  You can also read it on a [google doc here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qXTqXImb9yjz3CQkIaxh0K6P-PJTEDghFwfrjnpNty8/edit?usp=sharing) that has the formatting intact, so it's much easier to follow:

```
xdebug

xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.2.2
IDE Key PHPSTORM

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   /var/log/xdebug.log /var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Comment: here is the jetbrains docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-php-remote-debug.html

Comment: although I would suggest you don't debug on a production server...

Comment: @Ian Wood : I've been through the docs a few times and still can't figure it out.  Also, it's not a production server, it's a clone I asked them to setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem I need xdebug.remote_connect_back because I don't have a static IP.  I'll post again after I have them add it and it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible on remote server, because you need configure php.ini, that your server would listen xdebug.

"but have FTP (not SFTP) access to most of the files (I can't get to php.ini for example)."

Comment: What do you mean "configure php.ini, that your server would listen xdebug" specifically?  Xdebug is already setup on the remote server for me.  Is there something more I would need to do in php.ini?

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Edit_PHP.INI_File_for_XDebug, only xdebug.remote_host=localhost should be not localhost. Maybe you can attach additionaly phpinfo screen part starting with xdebug, because I've never seen prepared server by default, so I suspect that it is not there.

Comment: I've added the phpinfo() section.  It wasn't there by default.  I requested they install it.